# Full Calendar month name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I successfully installed FullCalendar besieds MVC.
And I also show the meetings within my database.

But why is the month name not showing up?

Starting month should be March, but it is not showing.  And when you start clicking "Next month" the events of april get shown.  But then it should be already April, and indeed, the events and the month is april but the title is not April.

Than only when you click previous, the events of March are showing.

Did I forget to initialize the month?

Sample:
http://www.jeroenchristens.be/MyCalendars

Code:

```
@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },

                defaultView: 'month',
                editable: true,
                allDaySlot: false,
                selectable: true,
                slotMinutes: 15,
                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetEvents", "MyCalendars")',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (doc) {
                            var events = [];                         
                            $(doc).each(function () { 
                                events.push({
                                    title: $(this).attr('title'),  
                                    start: $(this).attr('start'), 
                                    end: $(this).attr('end'),
                                    id: $(this).attr('id')
                                });
                            });
                            callback(events);
                        },                                                                    
                        error: function () {
                            alert("There was an error fetching events!");
                        }
                    });

                }

            });


        });
    </script>

}
<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**GetEvent Method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetEvents()
{
    var events = _context.Afspraken.ToList();
    var eventList = from e in events

        select new
        {

            id = e.Typeafspraakid,

            title = e.Afspraaktitel,

            start = e.Datumafspraak.ToString("s"),

            end = e.Datumafspraak.AddHours(1).ToString("s"),

            allDay = false

        };
    var rows = eventList.ToArray();
    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: your linked site is not accessible - it is password protected.

Comment: Also what version of fullCalendar are you using? The "theme" option is deprecated and shouldn't be used for new code. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/theme

Comment: Nonetheless, even with that mistake, the problem is not obviously reproducible. See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/435/ - it works fine (using a recent fullCalendar - v3.4) and the month name is displayed correctly.

Comment: I can only think that maybe some error is occurring with fetching the events which is causing JavaScript to crash and not display everything properly. Or you have the wrong version of the calendar, or jquery, or momentJS. Read https://fullcalendar.io/support and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/installation and then check your code to see if you added the correct version of everything, in the correct order.

Comment: Another side issue - why not make your "GetEvents" method produce JSON which is already compatible with fullCalendar? Then you don't need to have the extra ".each" loop in the "success" function, which is just adding unnecessary overhead. It is not difficult to make a C# object which has the correct structure, and then MVC will serialise it for you (if your action method returns a JsonResult).

Comment: i took the password off, sorry...

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you address my other points as well, please

Comment: The data is fine, but it is not showing the first tme, when the page loads.  GetEvents method loads all the events in the controller.

Comment: "The data is fine". If it's not showing the data, then that fact is potentially disputable, IMO. If there's a problem with your JSON (not invalid JSON, but simply JSON which doesn't match the expected format), then fullCalendar will silently fail to display the events. Also worth checking if the dates are actually the dates you intended. Possibly the events are simply being displayed somewhere else. Also, you never mentioned this before, you said the issue was with displaying a month name. Have you tried checking in your browser console for errors, and/or logging the event data there?

Comment: the first time it loads, there is no data, but hen you click next and than previous, the data is correct, (March).  The months are fine too (march from 1 to 31, april from 1 to 30, ...)   !!The month name is not set properly

Comment: I installed everything from scratch, but it didn't work.  So I copies files from the sample project, I downloaded, with an older version (2.4.0) of FullCalender.css and .js  So I took the newer files (3.8.2) and put them in the place of the older version in /content/ and /script.  But still no difference.  I am only trying local now.  Maybe I copied to much files.

Comment: There is also no difference between the standard template and the south-street template

Comment: it's already returning JSon result: return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: none of that tells me what you _actual data_ is, which is what told you to look at. Nor does it tell me what's in your console. Most of what you've just said is information I already knew. Good that you upgraded the fullCalendar version, although you neglected to inform me whether you checked the versions of jQuery,  and momentJS as well, which I also suggested. If I have time I'll take a look at your link myself, but you don't seem to have followed the requests I made. Do you understand what your browser console is and where to find it?

Comment: jQuery 3.1.1 and moment.js version : 2.11.1

Comment: yes, I know that too, the Console

Comment: after changing some things and updating the versions of a few files, it is working perfectly offline...  I also put <link> instead of import in my html file, it seems to go more efficient they tell me

Comment: now it seems to work fine too also on the url, thanks to a few changes, the month is displaying well, and the data is also loaded the first time also.  Even no difference between base theme and south street theme.  I followed the guidelines, but somehow forgot something.  thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

now it seems to work fine too also on the url, thanks to a few changes, the month is displaying well, and the data is also loaded the first time also. Even no difference between base theme and south street theme. I followed the guidelines, but somehow forgot something. thanks for pointing.

upgraded the versions of fullcalendar.css and .js
the difference between import and  might also help

you can try my link, it is database-binded.

Comment: in the browser console you can still see some error-messages:  bootstrap Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2jquery Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: sounds like you still have file files missing then. A 404 means the file requested by the browser couldn't be found. So check that those links in the HTML are correct, and that you copied the files to the right place on the server. Also double check whether you definitely need them. Glad you got it to work. Although for future readers, this doesn't really provide a useful answer - "a few changes"...well, if someone comes along and reads this with a similar problem, they don't really know what you changed, it doesn't help them. The point of SO is to be a repository for the future.

Comment: I got it to work after I updated the fullcalender.css and fullcalender.js like I told.  That are those changes.

Comment: Ah ok, in the answer it seems like you said "might also help", although that sentence does not entirely make sense, so it's hard to be sure. I think there is at least one word missing, and maybe also some punctuation.